# Eloquent: Relationships

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a big problem with the relation between two tables.
I want to link Subscription to Orders like this :

`$subs = Subscription::first()->order->id`

But nothing work i tried everything.

**Subscription table** : [image]

**Order table** : [image]

I tried this model but it don't work :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subscription extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Order');
    }
}
```

Order model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function payouts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Payout');
    }

    public function subscription()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subscription');
    }
}
```

## error :

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/trafficshield.tools/httpdocs/app/Http/Controllers/CampaignController.php:58

Line 58 : $order_id = Subscription::where('id', '=', 'GjhQpVSdQPirGmEEkJ6pGw')->first()->order->id;
```

Thank's for your

Comment: can you post you order model?

Comment: Just added order model

Comment: an order can have one or many Subscription?

Comment: An order can have only one subscription

Comment: i think its ok to me, what error are you getting?

Comment: ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$order in /var/www/vhosts/trafficshield.tools/httpdocs/app/Http/Controllers/CampaignController.php:58

Comment: You haven't shown us that code ...

Comment: $order_id = Subscription::where('id', '=', 'GjhQpVSdQPirGmEEkJ6pGw')->first()->order->id; you missing the first() to actuallty get the subscription

Comment: Yes I edited the code, I did a mistake,

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: post a dd(Subscription::where('id', '=', 'GjhQpVSdQPirGmEEkJ6pGw')->first())

Comment: https://puu.sh/xlGIR/e991161085.png @LeonardoCabré

Comment: @LeonardoCabré it's not a problem with postgreSQL ? Id to long or something else :/

Comment: i really don´t know whats happening -.-

Comment: First time I use string as ID and first time I have this issue.
The relation Order to Subscription work fine. I don't understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153059/discussion-between-leonardo-cabre-and-pixel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a non autoincrement value as primary key you have to put this in your models:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: I have this error : ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/trafficshield.tools/httpdocs/app/Http/Controllers/CampaignController.php:58